# Calling a closing method in spring boot application is the tomcat server is shut down

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I have a Spring Boot application which can be shut down anytime manually by the user. The application pushes data into the messaging queue read from a file. I want to call a method which should persist the state upto which the the file was read if the application is shut down.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the spring boot shutdown hook to do the logic by yourself.

> Application exit
>
> Each SpringApplication will register a shutdown hook with the JVM to ensure that the ApplicationContext is closed gracefully on exit. All the standard Spring lifecycle callbacks (such as the DisposableBean interface, or the @PreDestroy annotation) can be used.
>
> In addition, beans may implement the org.springframework.boot.ExitCodeGenerator interface if they wish to return a specific exit code when the application ends.

[23.8 Application exit](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-application-exit)